Эмуляция работы прошивки UEFI
Разрабатываю драйвер под UEFI и хочу протестировать его работу в виртуальной среде. Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ эмуляции работы прошивки материнской платы (в неё и будет встраиваться драйвер). Желательно чтобы был способ проброса PCI-устройств

Ну, просто взять любую виртуальную машину, наверное? Поддержка UEFI есть и в QEMU, и в VirtualBox, и в VMware (и все трое вроде как заявляют поддержку проброса PCI, хотя и с нюансами)

Чтобы вирт.машина могла получить доступ к BIOS/EFI мат.платы, она должна иметь встроенный отладчик. У Qemu, Vbox, VMware нет такого функционала, и соответственно они не могут отлаживать даже загрузчики ОС, не говоря уже о биос. Единственная VM с дебагом на борту - это BOCHS, хотя сомневаюсь, что и она сможет работать с BIOS/EFI.
